# How to convert this tradingview pinescript to C#?

Tags: c#, pine-script

I want to convert this tradingview function to C# but I am stuck with the logic and data types. This is a machine learning algorithm. I am not a math or coder profession so please help me with it. I need loss and prediction data at the end of the code. Problem arises on the loss equation inside the for loop.

```
//user defined functions
lookback   = 2
nlbk       = 2
lrate      = 0.0009
iterations = 1000

dot(v, w, p) => sum(v * w, p)  // dot product

sigmoid(z) => 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-z))

logistic_regression(X, Y, p, lr, iterations) => 
    w = 0.0, loss = 0.0
    for i=1 to iterations
        hypothesis = sigmoid(dot(X, 0.0, p))  //-- prediction
        loss := -1.0 / p * (dot(dot(Y, log(hypothesis) + (1.0 - Y), p), log(1.0 - hypothesis), p)) 
        gradient = 1.0 / p * (dot(X, hypothesis - Y, p))
        w := w - lr * gradient               //-- update weights
    
    [loss, sigmoid(dot(X, w, p))]            //-- returns current loss & prediction

//-------Using logistic regression function in algorithm

base= close     //close values of stock data except last (unclosed) bar
synth= log(abs(pow(close, 2) - 1) + .5)

[loss, prediction] = logistic_regression(base, synth, lookback, lrate, iterations)


///--------CSHARP CODE needs to be corrected

        public static object logistic_regression(double[] X, double[]  Y, int p,double lr,int  iterations)
        {
            var w = 0.0;
            var loss = 0.0;
            //double[] dotw = new double[X.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Enumerable.Range(0, iterations).ToList().Count(); i++)
            {
            //foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, iterations))
            {
                //var hypothesis = sigmoid(dot(X, dotw, p));
                double hypothesis = sigmoid(0);
                loss = -1.0 / p * dot(dot(Y, Math.Log(0.5) + (1.0 - Y), p), Math.Log(1.0 - 0.5), p);
                var gradient = 1.0 / p * dot(X, hypothesis - Y, p);
                w = w - lr * gradient;
            }
            new List<object> {
                loss,
                sigmoid(dot(X, w, p))
            };
        }

        public static double summ(double[] X, int Y)
        {
            double total = 0;
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, Y))
            {
                total = total + X[i];
            }
            return total;
        }

        public static double dot(double[] v, double [] w, int p)
        {
            double total = 0;
            List<double> sayilar = new List<double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
            {
                sayilar.Add(v[i] * w[i]);
            }

            total = summ(sayilar.ToArray(), p);

            return total;
        }
        public static double sigmoid(double z)
        {
           return 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.Exp(-z));
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code you already have in C#

Comment: Hello I added the csharp code. I wrote it with my friend. Actually he tried to code it but we stucked with the data types.

Comment: I think problem arises with dot function. we couldn't code that multiplies a vector with a scalar.